# How do I sort and add unique array options to a DropDownList using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an array of objects “AllClaimants” that has 2 properties (UserInfo & UserID);

Example:

```
AllClaimants[AllClaimantsCounter].UserInfo = "Santhalingam Sugirtha, 1980-06-05";
AllClaimants[AllClaimantsCounter].UserID = "1076073";
```

My `AllClaimants[AllClaimantsCounter].UserInfo` information contains 2 things “Name + Date of Birth”.

How can I sort (by UserInfo - in Userinfo I want to sort it by Name part only not by Date of Birth) and add unique values to select dropdown (ClaimantsDropDown) with text as `AllClaimants[AllClaimantsCounter].UserInfo` and value as `AllClaimants[AllClaimantsCounter].UserID`?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Your web page should be a dumb as possible so it shouldn't be modifying the incoming data, the function supplying the data should be formatting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array to List with

```
Array.AsList(array)
```

and the use linq with something like

```
list.OrderBy(x=> x.Key)
```

And depend on the type of the dropdrown you have to fill it, if it is a dropdown from aspnet server control you could use the list as datasource.